How might one translate "freedom and rebelliousness"?
As title states, I'm curious how one might translate the above terms (whether for simplified or traditional). From what I've seen, 自由 seems to be a pretty unanimous pick for translating "freedom" (though I'm not super convinced it might mean the exact same general concept), but the translation for rebelliousness seems much harder? (The most I've been able to find is akin to "rebel", "rebellious", etc.)

Prometheus was the original "rebel without a cause". He stole fire from the Olympian Gods and gave it to humans. Zeus was not happy about this. He tied Prometheus to a rock and, every day an eagle came and ate Prometheus' liver. Overnight, his liver regrew, but, next day, the eagle came again .....
"O woe is me, my life is a misery."
rebelliousness: 叛逆, 反叛
free: 自由
普罗米修斯的叛逆
Promethean rebelliousness
I think I had a little streak of rebelliousness too.
我想我有一点反叛连胜了。
His freedom is illusory.
他的自由是虚幻的。
This voyage was his first taste of freedom.
这次航行使他第一次体验到自由的滋味。

Based on the definitions below, I think this translation makes sense:
"freedom and rebelliousness" - "沒有拘束和不服控制".
Freedom - the state of being free or at liberty, or the absence of coercion, necessity, or constraint.
Rebelliousness - resisting the established authority, government, or tradition; insubordinate and inclined to rebel.
Rebel - A rebel is one who lives totally according to his own light and risks everything else for his ultimate value of freedom.

自由与反叛 or 自由与反叛精神. I don’t really know the subtle difference that you mentioned though.

freedom有一个意思: the right or privilege of unrestricted access
举例：
freedom of speech 翻译为中文：言论自由
freedom of movement 翻译为中文：行动自由
the four freedoms 翻译为中文：(美国总统富兰克林罗斯福所提倡的)四大自由(指言论自由、信仰自由、免于恐惧的自由和免于匮乏的自由)
rebelliousness有一个意思: unwilling to obey rules or follow generally accepted standards of behaviour, dress, etc. 反叛的；叛逆的；桀骜不驯的
例如：
rebellious teenagers 翻译为中文：叛逆的青少年
当然 rebelliousness 还有其他意思: Engaged in opposition or armed resistance to an established government or leader.（人、城市等）反叛的，造反的
举例：
the rebellious republics 翻译为中文：反叛的加盟共和国。
